# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 + Microsoft.Web.Mvc 3.0 + MEF compatibility

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mef

When i have an reference to Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll in my ASP.NET MVC 3.0 project i am getting an error when i am building `DirecotryCatalog` in my `CustomDependencyResolver`.

```
string path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/bin");
 var container = new DirectoryCatalog(path);
```

Then i looked at `container.Parts.Results View.LoadedExeptions` and it is saying:

***+[0]{"Method 'GetControllerSessionBehavior' in type 'Microsoft.Web.Mvc.MvcDynamicSessionControllerFactory' from assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.":"Microsoft.Web.Mvc.MvcDynamicSessionControllerFactory"}    System.Exception {System.TypeLoadException}***

***+[1]{"Method 'GetControllerSessionBehavior' in type 'Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Resources.ResourceControllerFactory' from assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.":"Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Resources.ResourceControllerFactory"}  System.Exception {System.TypeLoadException}***

Just for test i removed reference to Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll(physically removing it from bin direcotry) and then everything just fine. Looks like Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll couldn't be loaded.

Is there any work around?

I found similar issue here http://forums.asp.net/t/1622399.aspx?MVC+3+RC.+Where+is+the+Futures+Assembly%3F the answer saying that MVC 3 Beta Futures + MVC 3 RC Runtime = are incompatible. But i am using both RTM versions:

**Microsoft.Web.Mvc** Runtime version v4.0.30319, Version 3.0.0.0 (downloaded from here http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/releases/view/59313)

**System.Web.Mvc** Runtime version v4.0.30319, Version 3.0.0.0

**UPDATED:**

As Darin Dimitrov menthioned in his answer i need to exclude System.Web.Mvc from scanning process.
Here is the way how to do that:

```
public class SafeDirectoryCatalog : ComposablePartCatalog
{
    private readonly AggregateCatalog _catalog;

    public SafeDirectoryCatalog(string directory)
    {
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        _catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            try
            {
                var asmCat = new AssemblyCatalog(file);

                //Force MEF to load the plugin and figure out if there are any exports
                // good assemblies will not throw the RTLE exception and can be added to the catalog
                if (asmCat.Parts.ToList().Count > 0)
                    _catalog.Catalogs.Add(asmCat);
            }
            catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException)
            {
            }
        }
    }
    public override IQueryable<ComposablePartDefinition> Parts
    {
        get { return _catalog.Parts; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MEF chokes because it is scanning all assemblies in the `bin` folder which contain interfaces and classes and the `MvcDynamicSessionControllerFactory` class which implements `IControllerFactory` happens to be sealed. So the only solution I see here is to exclude the `Microsoft.Web.Mvc` assembly from this *scanning* process. I am not familiar with MEF but in StructureMap which has the same problem you could exclude types.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, it might help others to know that you can also get this exception when you attempt to load the same assembly from multiple locations.

In my situation, I changed the build drop location of a plugin assembly that I was working on without cleaning it from the previous location. As a result, the application was loading the same assembly from both locations and barfed up this exception. Cleaning the build drop solved the issue.

The `SafeDirectoryCatalog` is helpful/handy to not crash your application, but MEF still won't load your assemblies.